# Codeigniter UTF-8 in loaded view within another view

Tags: php, codeigniter, utf-8, codeigniter-3

I'm having a strange issue with loaded views in Codeigniter 3.0.1. 
I'm trying to display Spanish characters within my application. I have set these settings below to get Spanish displaying properly in the initial view loaded from my controller.

This is set in the main index.php of codeigniter.

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

I also have set this on the top of my HTML page mark up.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

So Spanish characters in the main HTML page is displaying properly. The problem is when I try to load another view inside the main HTML file.

```
<html>
<body>

  spanish here //displays properly

  <?php $this->load->view("page/somepage"); //Spanish in view does not format properly ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Any Spanish characters loaded inside this view is not formatting properly. 
Anybody know a work around?

Comment: Is that something from DB or static text? Post examples of what you get and what you want.

Comment: It's just a php file with some html being pulled in. like include(); Nothing from the database. Just html inside the included file with spanish text.

Comment: Have you tried something with text helper and `ascii_to_entities()` function or similar combination? If it is static text, you can use ascii code for patricular characters.

Comment: Yes that did it! Thank you!!